# CSS absolute positioning nightmare—browser differences

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have some code that will allow me to have a couple of `div`s pop up with HTML in them.

I got it pixel perfect in Firefox and then realised that all the other browsers (not tested in IE) are off.

Could anyone tell me or show me an article on how different browsers treat absolute positioned elements and how to correct my dilemma?

Here is [my original code](http://jsfiddle.net/jamcoupe/kcF9Z/), and here is [my new code](http://jsfiddle.net/jamcoupe/kcF9Z/5/).

This is what I am seeing:

[image: Photo of differences]

Comment: I don't think that's an css positioning issue, change the none display to block and you'll see that the divs are there in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out what I was doing wrong. I created a `div` around the `p` tag and then set the width to what I wanted because before it calculated the space by using padding around the `p` here is my updated code that works perfectly! (I hope)

Updated code: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jamcoupe/kcF9Z/7/)**

---

**Edit:**
I had the *hidden* boxes outside each of the visible boxes (where you click to show the hidden ones) so it when I was trying to position them it was not easy to determine where they were going to be in the DOM but if you make the *hidden* boxes a child of the visible boxes respectively then you can use `position: relative;` CSS property to position the child boxes *exactly* where you want them!

**CSS**

```
.visibleBox{
     position: relative;
}

.hiddenBox{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0; 
     right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="visibleBox">
    <p class="hiddenBox">I am hidden sometimes<p>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to say is that I have the `P` outside of the `DIV` and this was making it totally awkward to position it correctly in all browsers but using the parent and child with the relative and absolute position it fixed my issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you had. It's a nightmare... I do not understand your final solution. I still do not understand why the position is slightly different by pixels..

Comment: Added more details above @DanielRamirez-Escudero hopefully it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

In all browsers the absolute positioning is defined the same way.

Elements are positioned absolutely to a relative/absolute positioned parent or the body element if not such.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me in IE9, Chrome 17 and FF9. adding position relative to div#userControls will ensure you are positioning absolute nodes relative to its parent node.

Comment: I have added the position relative to div#userControls but I am still seeing a difference. I added a picture.

Comment: this is what is see in my chrome. http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/626521-18201280912PM